# Optimization algorithm to find acceptable limits of a concave function

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have a black box function `f(x)` with the following criteria:

- it is [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) within a certain range.
- it is [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)

Within Python, I would like to get an algorithm that delivers to me - with the least amount of steps - the positions `x0`, `x1` where `f` is greater or equal to `a`.

It can be assumed that there exist values for `x` where `f(x)` is greater/equal than `a`.

See this picture for visualizing the problem:

[image]

So my questions are:

- What would be the name for such an algorithm, if there is one (like there is e.g. the `bubble sort algorithm` when the task is to sort a list)?
- How would an algorithm for my problem look like?
- Alternatively: Is there a standard Python library for such task?

Comment: This is basically a root finding algorithm, like *Newton-Rhapson*.

Comment: *"...concave within a certain range."*: is this range given as input?

Comment: *"...there exist values for x where f(x) is greater/equal than a"*: should only those in the concave range be identified? And does this statement hold true for the concave range?

Comment: are X0 and X1 points inside the concave region where f > a or boundaries of the closed interval where f >= a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for points where a function crosses the x-axis is `zero-finding` or x-axis intercept finding. You can define a new function g(x) = f(x) - a then find the 'zeros' of  the g(x) function.

The simplest way of finding intercepts is to find an xa and xb where g(xa) < 0 and g(xb) > 0. Then choose an xc midway between those and continue using xc and one of xa or xb (that has the opposite sign as xc). Repeat these steps again until the interval between x's is small enough to be considered 'found'.